# Create Perl Regex to "Not Match" Specific Emails

Tags: regex, perl, cpanel

To help fight spam, I've set up multiple "Global Email Filters" for a domain in cPanel, however these filters now appear to have overridden the cPanel "Default Address = Discard" setting that I have in place! So I am now trying to recreate the rule so that non-existant-user@mydomain.co.uk (spam) emails get discarded Eg.

Email To (matches PERL regex):

If Does Not Match This john OR peter OR luke @mydomain.co.uk

Action:

Discard

*So john123@mydomain.co.uk would be a MATCH and be discarded BUT

john@mydomain.co.uk or peter@mydomain.co.uk or luke@mydomain.co.uk would NOT be a match and be accepted for delivery.

I'm hoping you can create this "PERL" regex for me.

I've already tried this but it doesn't work -

```
(?!.*(john|peter|luke@mydomain.co.uk))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!(?:john|peter|luke)\@mydomain\.co\.uk\z)
```

This matches everything except

- `john@mydomain.co.uk`
- `peter@mydomain.co.uk`
- `luke@mydomain.co.uk`

---

```
^(?!(?:john|peter|luke)\@(?:local\.)?mydomain\.co\.uk\z)
```

This matches everything except

- `john@mydomain.co.uk`
- `peter@mydomain.co.uk`
- `luke@mydomain.co.uk`
- `john@local.mydomain.co.uk`
- `peter@local.mydomain.co.uk`
- `luke@local.mydomain.co.uk`

---

You can make these case-insensitive by wrapping the whole in `(?i:...)`.

Comment: Great, it works! I've slightly improved on this to allow for a non-match of one of my sub.domains too "john@local.mydomain.co.uk" is now not matched by this:

**^(?!(?:john|peter|luke)\@(?:(local\.))?domdom\.co\.uk\z)**

It appears to partially work however I'm not sure it's totally syntax correct as it now produces a non-match for john@.mydomain.co.uk (note the .dot between @ and mydomain string). Only john@[server.]mydomain.co.uk should produce a non-match. Any ideas on how I should correct it?

Comment: @Mark, The pattern you provided has a needless set of capture. But otherwise, it will match everything but the six strings it shouldn't match (the the previously mentioned plus the versions with `local.`.